# Attach a static library to Tweak.xm in iOS Jailbroken

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I am new to Mobile Substrate Tweak in iOS please correct me if I am wrong .I am successful in creating a Mobile Substrate tweak by following the link

https://www.andyibanez.com/create-mobilesubstrate-tweaks-ios/

Now I want to Import  my static library to the Tweak.xm so that i can perform some special actions which is written in my static library .

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy  framework to Xcode in your Mac. /Users/iavtech/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
2. add in makefile nameapphook_FRAMEWORKS = nameframework

3.Call header normal in your code .

It's work for me.